# Advice needed on what to do with a new elementary method of factoring integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

I literally stumbled on this really elementary (but promising) method of factoring integers. My maths knowledge being limited, I am not in a position to judge how efficient the method is with handling large numbers. I am wondering what my next steps should be. Should I post it here or just provide enough details so others can implement it and check it for themselves? (Sadly, I cannot code so I will not be able to do meaningful calculations myself).

Comment: For those interested, I am willing to send them the write-up as soon as I have it.

Comment: OK, post your method...

Comment: Before sending material, compare with some literature, e.g., start reading the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) and the references given therein. It might then be clear if it is new or not.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I did and it's not in there.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, thank you.

Comment: Then edit the question and post your method with one very simple example everyone can understand (and check if it is new or not). For example, what does your method give for $n=2^9-1$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, my answer below needs to be cleaned up and properly formatted. I am hoping someone will do that and edit the question. Sorry for that. And I will thank them before they do it. To answer your question about n=511=7*73. This method will get the answer quickly because it really does not care about the gap between two factors. The factors can be as close or as far apart as you want them to be and it won't make any difference.

Comment: factoring N = 7*73 = 511 = 14*36 + 7. We know that a remainder of 7 in N is associated with the remainders of (0,14) for N_1 and N_2. set s+t = 2n = 2*7 = 14 but also i+j = 2*14 = 28. Possibles for (s,t) are (0,14), (7,7) because these are allowed values. Now we need to split 28 into pairs of coefficients of 36 so we can build N_1 and N_2. The first possible pair is (14,14), others are (13,15), (12,16)...so now we can start building N_1 and N_2. 
N_1=14*36 + 0= 14*36= 7*72, 
N_2=14*36 + 14=14*36 +14=7*74. 
So by taking the GCD of (N,N_1) or GCD(N,N_2) we see they have 7 as a common factor.

Answer (score 0):

Given a number $N=pq$ ( with $p>q$), this method is about building two numbers $N_1$ and $N_2$ whose sum adds up to $N$. There are of course many pairs $((N-1, N+1),...)$ but we consider only numbers that share a factor with $N$.

The closest number that share a factor with $N$ are $N_1$ = $(p-1) \cdot q = N - q$ and $N_2=(p+1) \cdot q = N + q$ but they are also the ones with the smallest gap since $N_2-N_1=2q$. These two numbers sandwich $N$ and share a factor with it. Notice that we have $N_1+N_2 = 2N$.

I am limiting myself to showing how the method works for number of the form $N=(6k+1)$ but the method can be expanded to other forms.

Now we express $N$ as $N = 36n + r$ and similarly $N_1 = 36i + s$ and $N_2 = 36j + t$. Because $N$ is the average of $N_1$ and $N_2$, we can see that the coefficients $(n,i,j)$ of $36$ and the remainders $(r,s,t)$ have similar average relations but not always as simple as $a + b = c/2$.

We obviously don't have $N_2-N_1$ or $N_1 \cdot N_2$ to use it with $N_2+N_1=2N$ to determine the factors so we have first to construct $N_1$ and $N_2$. It turns out that it is possible to build $N_1$ and $N_2$ from $N$ and from additional information that can be extracted from the behavior of numbers of the form $(6k+1)$. To begin with these numbers have only $3$ possible sum of digits: $1, 4,$ or  $7$. This property is behind the patterns specific to these numbers and we will show how to exploit them to construct $N_1$ and $N_2$.

The numbers $N=(6k+1)$ can only have a remainder of $1,7,13,19,25,$ or $31$ when expressed as $N = 36n + r$. We need to find the patterns that are displayed by these numbers for a given sum of digits ($SD$). In the following we will restrict ourselves to the sum of digits $SD=7$. This sum of digits can be produced by multiplying numbers with these pairs of $SD$'s: $7 \times 1$, $4 \times 4$, $2 \times 8$, and $5 \times 5$. We are looking for patterns in $(r,s,t)$ and the coefficients. Basically we need to find out which $r$ is associated with the pair $(s,t)$.

It is easy to make a table for $SD=7$ and each of the four type of products $7 \times 1$, $4 \times 4$, $2 \times 8$, and $5 \times 5$. I will only give the values for the product $7 \times 1$ (because I don't know how to make tables). From numerical experiments (done by hand), we see that the remainders $(r,s,t)$ can only take certain values and then they cycle through. I use the word periodic. So if I did not miss one or more, they are $(r,s,t)=(25,18,32)$ and $(7,0,14)$. Unless I missed some, these are the only values the remainders $(r,s,t)$ will take when a number is a product of a $7 \times 1$ factors. But we have no way of knowing before factoring a number with $SD=7$ is it was a product of a $7 \times 1$ or some other product among the four possibilities. This means that we will be doing a lot more work to build the numbers $N_1$ and $N_2$ than we would if we could somehow  tell the $SD$ of the original factors by looking at $N$ and maybe doing some tests (I could never figure out this problem).

So now we are ready to look at a really simple example to see how the method can be implemented.

We take $N = 7 \cdot 19 = 133 = 3 \cdot 36 + 25$. Because $r=25$, we know that the possible remainders are only those associated with $25$. There are few others than the ones listed above that come from products $4 \times 4$, $5 \times 5$ and $2 \times 8$. We know the answer so we will work backward. $N_1 = 7 \times 18 = 126 = 3 \times 36 + 18$ and $N_2 = 7 \times 20 = 140 = 3 \times 36 + 32$. So we can write $s + t = 2r$, and in terms of coefficients of $36$ we have $i + j = 2n$. The parity of $(n, i, j)$ plays a role in how we can write the average equations for the coefficients. In some cases, we need to borrow $1$ or $36$ to get the correct averages of *both*  $(n,i,j)$ and $(s,t,r$).

The above case is pretty straightforward and we see that the averages can be calculated independently of each other, which is not always the case but it's pretty easy to know when the averages are dependent because we can only have integer values for these averages.

So we now have $i+j = 2 \times 3 = 6$ and $s + t = 2 \times n = 2 \times 25 = 50$.

Because the numbers$ N, N_1,$ and $N_2$ are the closest they can be while sharing a factor, we can reasonably assume that the coefficients will also be close to each other. So when we go from the sum $2n=6$ to individual values for $i,j$, it is also reasonable to start with the pair $(3,3)$. But we need to keep in mind that the pair $(2,4)$ should also be considered. An important question to which I don't have an answer is how many pairs should be considered before we give up. It is obvious in the above example that the pair $(0,6)$ and $(1,5)$ can be safely discarded because  they would lead to numbers that cannot possibly share a factor with $N$. For $s + t = 50$, we can take the values $18$ and $32$ or $20$ and $30$ but certainly not $21$ and $29$ because $(21,29)$ is not a possible value.

So now we have the values of the remainders and the coefficients, we can build the numbers $N_1$ and $N_2$. One of the two is always divisible by $6$. It depends on the original factors form. If it is a $(6k+1)$, then $N_1 = (p-1) \cdot q = (6k+1-1) \cdot q=6k \cdot q$. If it is a $(6k-1)$ factor, $N_2$ will be divisible by $6$. A simple test to eliminate some values for $N_1$ and $N_2$. So we  get $N_1 = 3 \cdot 36 + 18 = 126$ and $N_2 = 3 \cdot 36 + 32 = 140$. Taking the $\gcd(N,N_1)$ or $\gcd(N,N_2)$ will tell us they share a factor.

And like all factoring methods, this one can be used to test a number for primality. In this case, pairs of numbers can always be built but none will have a common factor if $N$ is prime.

One advantage of the method is that the difference or gap between the numerical values of the factors that limits the efficiency of other methods ( Fermat's...) plays no role here.

I would really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: (@DietrichBurde) I can't understand what you wrote, but I can immediately tell it fails for even moderately sized semiprimes.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, can you provide the semi-prime of the form (6k+1) for which the method failed? I do the math by hand so please keep the numbers small.

Comment: Your algorithm is nigh unreadable and you leave many questions unanswered in your description. It's not _rigorous_ - and rigour is a key pillar of mathematics. Try doing RSA-100 (which can be factored in around five hours on a modern laptop).

Comment: I think that you have to actually explain everything more.  For instance, you claim that $6k+1$ has only 3 possible digit sums, but I see in Mathematica that there are many possible digit sums.  You may have to state that you're taking these sums modulo 9, for instance.  Or, to use the same example, you could take DigitSum[DigitSum[$6k+1$]].

Comment: @Sloan, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @MattGroff, I did say that my maths knowledge is limited so I wasn't aware that the sum of digits I used was taken modulo 9. But that is the one I had in mind even if I was not aware that many others are possible. And in this case, there are only 3, (1,4,7). I will be glad to explain if and when I can if you tell me exactly what needs more explaining.

Comment: Thanks - I'm also a fairly big believer in elementary methods...  Anyways, you talk about making a table for SD=7 and four types of products: $7 \times 1$, $4 \times 2$, $2 \times 8$, $5 \times 5$...  I'm wondering where these values come from...  I guess right now I'm trying to see exactly how your method works - it is interesting, but factoring is a very tough problem.

Comment: @MattGroff, The coefficients change rapidly but the remainders are periodic, meaning the same remainder will occur many times. The data comes from numerical experiments. If the remainders changed every time we change a factor or two, we will not have a method. If I want to know which remainder are produced when I multiply 7x1 factors, I take 7 as a factor, then vary the 2nd factor (19+18k). After a little while, you see the periodicity of the remainders. for a 2x8, I take 11*(17+18k)...

Comment: @MattGroff. I can't put all the answer in one comment so this is a (cont). I make a multiplication table for the sum of digits. (6k+1) factors can only have a sum of digits of 1,4,7. (6k-1) factors can only have 2,8,5 sum of digits. then you make the multiplication table (1,4,7)*(1,4,7) and you get your matrix. The same for (6k-1), (2,5,8)*(2,5,8). when you look at these two matrices, you see that a 7x1 = 7 number can be produced by (7x1),(4*4),(2*8),(5*5=25=2+5=7). Then you select factors with these sum of digits and you multiply them and you look at the remainders.

Comment: Ok, it's a lot more clear.  Basically, you're working with remainders modulo sets of numbers, and finding patterns.  For example, if $x = 6k+1$ for some integer $k$, we say that $x$ is 1 modulo $6$, or write $x \bmod 6 \equiv 1$.  I don't mean to disappoint, but things like this have been studied before.  If we're working modulo a prime number - for example, $x \bmod p = y$, where $y$ is a prime number, we can construct any number if we use enough primes.  Say we know $x \bmod 2 \equiv 1$ and $x \bmod 3 \equiv 2$, we have $x \bmod (3 \cdot 2) \equiv 5$.  This is Chinese remainder theorem...

Comment: Working modulo primes, we have finite fields, part of abstract algebra.  Working modulo composites, which are products of primes, we have rings, part of abstract algebra.  Number theory also touches on these items.  I'm just trying to give you places to start.          The main problem with working with patterns of remainders is that you have to gather lots of information, and it generally takes a long time to process.  I'm wondering what you'd like to know about your algorithm, for now?

Comment: I counted 5 cases where a remainder of 25 (if I didn't miss any) appears for N with SD=7. This means that we only need to look at 5 different cases, 4 of which will not give  the correct answer, before we get N_1 and N_2 for a given N. Here they are. (18,25,32),(12,25,2),(20,25,30),(14,25,0),(30,25,20). For a small number, it may appear to be a lot but for a big one, it's not a big effort, it's 5x2 averages to get the numbers. 
I just want to know if the method is worth pursuing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46755/discussion-between-matt-groff-and-user25406).